# Why can Echelon Matrices have zero rows but Echelon systems can't have any equations with no leading variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

According to the definition my professor gave us its okay for a matrix in echelon form to have a zero row, but a system of equations in echelon form cannot have an equation with no leading variable.

Why is this? Aren't they supposed to represent the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: What's a “leading variable”?

Comment: The non-zero variable furthest to the left in a row.

Answer (score 0):

I think the distinction you're referring to is the difference between the echelon forms of the *coefficient* matrix of a system versus the *augmented* matrix of the system. Suppose you have the system

$
ax_1+bx_2=c
$

$
dx_1+ex_2=f.
$

Then there is the coefficient matrix $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}
a & b \\ d & e \\ \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

and there is the augmented matrix $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\ \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$.

It may happen that the row reduced echelon form of the coefficient matrix has a zero row, e.g.  $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}
\ast & \ast \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$. However, if that row is not a zero row in the row reduced echelon form for the augmented matrix, then the rref of the augmented matrix looks like $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}
\ast & \ast & \ast \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$, and that last row corresponds to the equation

$
0x_1+0x_2=1
$
which is clearly a contradiction, hence the original system has no solutions.